# Ionic cordova resources –force not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

On add android/iOS platform or run `ionic cordova resources --force` this not is completed, always continue stopped in **Generating platform resources** step.

I verify that and in same times this generate **503** error on api call (https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/transform).

I check the ionic status (https://status.ionicframework.com/) but in there, all system is normal operational.

**EDIT**

My `ionic info`:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.6.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.1.0
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode  : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

My `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/header-color": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic/cli-utils": "^2.0.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-headercolor": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^2.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "^4.2.5",
    "ng-svg-icon-sprite": "^0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.11",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
}
```

My `ionic -v` is **CLI PRO 4.0.1**

**EDIT 2**

Some moments, the process return error (multiples), for example:

```
Generating platform resources - failed!
[ERROR] Resource server responded with an error.

    This could mean the server is experiencing difficulties right now--please try again later.

    Request: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/transform
    Response: 400
```

Anyone with this problem? Suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share more details? It would be good if you share your package.json file

Comment: @SandipLipane i added more informations!

Comment: Try deleting all the png's from icon and splash folder of ios and run "ionic cordova resources ios" command.

Comment: Please, check my new edit

Comment: This error occurs in all times if i try now...

Comment: I find an very recently topic on github about this problem... https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3385

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most probably related to the used image sizes not the force command itself.

Make sure that your icon has the following minimum size **(1200×1200 px)**

and your splash has the following minimum size **(2732×2732 px)** not (2208×2208 px).

Generate the resources using either of following commands

```
$ ionic cordova resources 
$ ionic cordova resources ios
$ ionic cordova resources android
```

Comment: Sir I have already used above resolution but got same error can you tell me how to fix error.                                                                
 HTTP Error 503: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload

Answer (score 1):

Those who are looking for an answer on Ionic4.

1) Install cordova-res globally as below:

```
   npm i -g cordova-res
```

2) Run

```
   ionic cordova resources
```

3) It will create splash and icon images inside the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

[https://tinypng.com/

Inside the resource folder I change Icon size

Icon from 106 Kb to 25 Kb

```
$ ionic cordova resources ios
$ ionic cordova resources android
```

Solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above issue after update Ionic CLI via below command:-

npm i -g ionic@latest

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on windows system while adding android to the new ionic project.

Error I got that is as follow:
`something went wrong installing the sharp module`

After some research I got the solution and that is

1. `npm uninstall -g cordova-res`.
2. `npm i -g cordova-res`

Hope it will helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I has similar issue which was not updating any resources to the android folder which I solve in those situations by manually removing the folder inside `android\app\main\res` except `values` & `xml` folder.

Then I run

```
cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

which will automatically generate the folders you have removed with the new ones from `resources` folder.

Hope this helps someone.